# Recreational activities for glass people

Tags: society, culture, aliens

This is related to [How can glass people survive?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9990/how-can-glass-people-survive).

So, I have glass people in my world. We already talked about how are they going to survive. Now, I want to know what recreational activities could they have? At first, I thought of making them hostile but now I want them to share their culture with humans.

The question is, what could their recreational activities be? I don't want these activities to be the same as humans (taking your kids to park, going out with family, soccer, television etc) but I want them to be a whole lot different. Recreational activities mean something that makes them happy and they enjoy doing it after a huge day work.

Comment: I think we can all agree that recreational stone throwing would be out.

Comment: @GrandmasterB Not really. It can be. But it can only be played once.

Comment: Laser tag would be cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd get a lot of romantic stuff with light.  Imagine couples viewing light that's passed through both of their bodies, or a picture of a beautiful sunset visible through a couple holding eachother.

As for games:

**Courtlight**

Courtlight is played with at least one light source, an object that can cast a shadow, and at least 3 players.  At least two objects are placed as goals in the shadowed area.  The object of Courtlight is to redirect light from the source into your goal, and to redirect light away from the opponent's goal.

Courtlight games can be extremely varied.  Street games usually involve the sun and a house.  Professional games generally use artificial lights of varied colors, and usually require combinations of colors to score.  Most involve at least 3 teams simultaneously playing, with each team sharing only one common color with other temas.  For example you might have Red, Blue and Yellow lights, and one team scores with Purple, one with Green, and one with Orange.

The only rule all Courtlight games share that hasn't been stated yet is that players must be constantly moving.  This rule is sometimes modified for handicapped players, but is never entirely ignored.  It is common for Courtlight to use zones that players are not allowed to leave, but some games do not have zones and even allow for physical contact.

Variations of Courtlight exist that use human players on teams as mobile light blockers.

Answer (score 8):

**Light performance**

If I were a glass person, I'd love sunlight or bright lights so I could play with refracting light, perhaps along to music.

This could be a beautiful performance in front of thousands, or a more private hobby they could do on their own or with family.

Comment: This is the most colorful answer I have ever read on any Stack Exchange platform so far. :)

Comment: In fact you could have a game a bit like twister, where there are beams of colored light and you need to position yourself to change the light somehow (for example point it at a certain position).

Comment: Or, like musicians can do playing wine glasses to produce music, can these glass people provide their own haunting tones to accompany their lights? Live crystallophone, maybe: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eq7Lbg1vqdE

Answer (score 1):

Maybe instead of going to the gym they cover themselves with sand and heat themselves up so gain more mass.

Comment: What a great idea.